# mysql left join take rows together

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables: invoice, person and payement.
I want to have a list of invoices with the client name (from person) and the sum of payements and dates of payements(from payement).

First I made these statement

```
SELECT V.id, V.datum, V.amount, P.name AS 'client', 
(SELECT SUM(B.amount) FROM payement AS B WHERE B.invoiceId = V.id) AS 'payed',
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(B.datum SEPARATOR ',') FROM payement AS B WHERE B.invoiceId = V.id) AS 'date payement'
FROM invoice AS V 
JOIN person AS P ON (V.clientId = P.id)
WHERE YEAR(V.datum) = '2015' 
ORDER BY V.datum;
```

This give what I want (p.e. a transaction of 1000 on 4 sept and one of 2400 on 10 sept), but works very slow when I have a lot of invoices.

```
+------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+---------------------+
| id   |  datum    | amount | client | payed | date payement       |
+------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+---------------------+
| 75   |2015-09-10 | 3400   |Sommers | 3400  |2015-09-04,2015-09-10|
+------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+---------------------+
```

So I tried another statement.

```
SELECT V.id, V.datum, V.amount, P.name AS 'client', B.amount AS 'payed', B.datum 'date payement'
FROM invoice AS V 
JOIN person AS P ON (V.clientId = P.id)
LEFT JOIN payement AS B ON B.invoiceId = V.id
WHERE YEAR(V.datum) = '2015' 
ORDER BY V.datum;
```

But this give me 2 rows for 1 invoice, when it is payed with 2 transactions.
Can I solve it with SQL, or is it better to solve it in my application (in Java)?

Answer (score 0):

When an invoice has been paid with 2 payments, which details do you wish to use? the first payment or the 2nd?

Assuming that you want the total payment amount and the latest payment date:-

```
SELECT V.id, 
        V.datum, 
        V.amount, 
        P.name AS 'client', 
        SUM(B.amount) AS 'payed', 
        MAX(B.datum) AS 'date payement'
FROM invoice AS V 
JOIN person AS P ON (V.clientId = P.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN payement AS B ON B.invoiceId = V.id
WHERE YEAR(V.datum) = '2015' 
GROUP BY V.id, 
        V.datum, 
        V.amount,
        P.name
ORDER BY V.datum
```

I don't use phpmyadmin.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT V.factuurnr, 
    ->         V.datum, 
    ->         V.somexcl, 
    ->         P.naam AS 'client', 
    ->         SUM(B.bedrag) AS 'payed', 
    ->         GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(B.datum,'%d/%m/%y') SEPARATOR ',') AS 'date payement'
    -> FROM verkoop AS V 
    -> JOIN persoon AS P ON (V.klantId = P.id)
    -> LEFT JOIN betaling AS B ON B.docId = V.id
    -> WHERE YEAR(V.datum) = '2015' and month(V.datum)=9
    -> GROUP BY V.factuurnr, 
    ->         V.datum, 
    ->         V.somexcl,
    ->         P.naam
    -> ORDER BY factuurnr;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref            | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | V     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL           | 1576 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | P     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | meta.V.klantId |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL           | 3291 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, however it is still slow but twice as fast as my first solution. As 'date payements' I do not need a date, but the concatenation of the different dates. So I used: GROUP_CONCAT(B.datum) SEPARATOR ',') instead of MAX(B.datum).

Comment: The indexes might need tweaking to improve performance. Also, using YEAR(V.datum) is going to require a function on every row without being able to use an index, but using WHERE V.datum BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2014-12-31' might be quicker.

Comment: As far as I can see is it the 'LEFT' join who take time.

Comment: Can you post the table definitions please. Also try an EXPLAIN on the query and post that.

Comment: Without LEFT it take 0.03 seconds, with LEFT it take 0.66 seconds.<br />But then I don't get the invoices without payement.<br />When I omit the LEFT and I do a UNION with the same statement without the JOIN payement, it take 0.08 seconds, but then I have multiple duplicates (as I red that the distinct don't work on 1 column).

Comment: If you can post the table definitions, etc, I will try and look in to it. Without them there is little I can do.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand to copy code here  ->     SELECT V.id, 
      V.invoiceNo
            V.datum, 
            V.amount, 
            P.name AS 'client', 
            SUM(B.amount) AS 'payed', 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(B.datum,'%d/%m/%y') SEPARATOR ',') AS 'date payement'
    FROM invoice AS V 
    JOIN person AS P ON (V.clientId = P.id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN payement AS B ON B.invoiceId = V.id
    WHERE YEAR(V.datum) = '2015' AND MONTH(V.datum) = 9
    GROUP BY V.id, 
      V.invoiceNo
            V.datum, 
            V.amount,
            P.name)
    ORDER BY invoiceNo;

Comment: Sorry,what I need is the table definitions (eg, if you use phpmyadmin then you can EXPORT the table declare). Also in phpmyadmin if you execute your above SQL but put EXPLAIN before the SELECT then it will show you details of what indexes will be used when the query is executed. If you can post those it will help (update your original post with it).

Comment: Looking at that, add an index on the docId column of the betaling table. That should improve the performance of the join quite substantially. Also add an index to verkoop  on the datum column and chage the line of sql from_WHERE YEAR(V.datum) = '2015' and month(V.datum)=9_ to _WHERE V.datum BETWEEN  '2015-09-01' AND '2015-0930'_ which will hopefully allow it to use that index on verkoop (assuming it is a date field).

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know the indexen. I added an index to docId, and query time went from 0.73 to 0.02 seconds. I tried before the change with BETWEEN (without the index) , but that didn't improve substantially.

Comment: With the index it should make a bigger difference.